# Return All MySQL Rows Where colA is Duplicated by colB Isn't

Tags: mysql, sql

We're trying to find data errors in a MySQL database and I can't figure out a way to handle this without thrashing the database.

Here's a mockup of the data:

```
Table: EXAMPLE
+-----+------+-------+
| ID  |  PID |  YEAR |
+-----+------+-------+
|     |      |       |
| 001 |  A   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 002 |  B   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 003 |  A   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 004 |  A   |  2009 |
|     |      |       |
| 005 |  B   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 006 |  C   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 007 |  C   |  2014 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

The goal is to return all rows where PID and YEAR are out of sync with one another. If there are three rows where the PID matches but the YEAR is wrong in any of them, we need to return all rows.

In the above example data, the following would be returned:

```
+-----+------+-------+
| ID  |  PID |  YEAR |
+-----+------+-------+
|     |      |       |
| 001 |  A   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 003 |  A   |  2014 |
|     |      |       |
| 004 |  A   |  2009 |
+-----+------+-------+
```

The query I've worked up thus far looks like this:

```
SELECT EXAMPLE.ID, EXAMPLE.PID, EXAMPLE.YEAR 
FROM EXAMPLE
INNER JOIN
(SELECT PID FROM EXAMPLE where PID HAVING COUNT(PID) > 1 GROUP BY PID) tmpTbl
ON EXAMPLE.PID = tmpTbl.PID
```

The problem is that in my real dataset, the subquery returns 26k of the 255k rows in the database.  The expected result is less "Here are your results" and more "Watch my processing animation".

Am I on the right track?  Is there a more efficient method that I am overlooking?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your subquery should be using `count(distinct)`.  That might speed the query a lot.  Also, the `having` should go after the `group by`.

Comment: the DISTINCT throws me no results.  The COUNT is in the correct place in my code, sorry about that.

Comment: . . Actually, that should be `count(distincdt year)`, because that's what you want to find discrepancies in.  You don't want just any `pid` that has more than one row (if I understand the question correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an `exists` subquery instead:

```
select e.*
from example e
where exists (select 1
              from example e2
              where e2.pid = e.pid and
                    e2.year <> e.year
             );
```

To have this run faster, create an index on `example(pid, year)`.

If you just want all the years and can take them in one row, then this might suffice:

```
SELECT PID, group_concat(year) as years
FROM EXAMPLE
where PID
GROUP BY PID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) > 1 ;
```

Comment: I tried running this and it still locked up everything and never returned the result.

Comment: @VSack . . . Did you run the first one with the index?

Comment: Good call, that is returning results in less than 2 minutes! Much better than crashing the server.

Only issue now is that it's not returning the pid.  Field just comes back blank.

Comment: Nevermind.  This dataset sucks.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT EXAMPLE.*
FROM
  EXAMPLE INNER JOIN (SELECT PID
                      FROM EXAMPLE
                      GROUP BY PID
                      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Year)>1) Dup
  ON Example.PID = Dup.PID
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68e24/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM example as e 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT PID FROM example as e1 
              WHERE e1.PID = e.PID AND e1.YEAR <> e.YEAR)
```

Comment: I tried running this and it still locked up everything and never returned the result.